# Why dosen't QCombo Box work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a Qcombobox and when I initialise the main window I set the first value using:

```
self.events.insertItem(0,'No Events')
```

It now looks like this:

[image]

I want to clear and repopulate the box several times so I use:

```
window.events.clear()
```

And then:

```
window.events.insertItem(0,'Some Events')
```

Before adding my events.

Now it looks like this:

[image]

And if I select the box:

[image]

Why is "Some Events" not written on the top line like "No Events" was?

How do I get "Some Events" written on the top line like "No Events" was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the current item in the combo box should fix this.

```
window.events.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes is doesn't... odd.I.E I keep clicking a "repopulate button" and sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: How are you doing the clearing? Usually it comes up blank that way when `currentIndex` is `-1`. You can confirm what `currentIndex` is by printing to console `print(window.events.currentIndex()).` How are events added? My hunch is that there is a race condition ongoing when you clear and when add events.

Comment: Adding Events using window.events.insetsItem(index,string)

Comment: Checking the current index show me that I have a bug because it prints multiple -1's so for some reason the loop is running multiple times. Need to check this.

Comment: Ok, fixed the bug, still getting the same behavior from the combo box.

Comment: Sorry, I was being an Idiot, I inserted the         window.events.setCurrentIndex(0) line before setting "some Events" - All working now, thanks for the help. :)